# relationship treating foreign key as an integer, not varchar

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got a table and a view in a postgres database: a `customer` table and a `cust_address_view` view. Connecting the two is an id column named `customer_id`. When I declare the relationship in `customer` to `customerAddress` it's treating the `customer_id` as an integer (or at least it's chopping off the leading zero) causing it to not find the records.

I have the relationship declared as such:

```
public function customerAddress()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CustomerAddress' , 'customer_id', 'customer_id');
}
```

For customer ID 012345 I'm seeing this query in the debugbar:

```
select * from "cust_address_view" where "cust_address_view"."customer_id" = '12345' and "cust_address_view"."customer_id" is not null
```

Is this an issue with one of the two being a view instead of both being a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Customer` class, you want to specify that `customer_id` cannot increment (i.e. not an integer)

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    ...
    public $incrementing = false;
    ...
}
```

That should tell Laravel to not use an integer to lookup the customer.

Comment: this did it, thank you! I didnt even realize that was a thing.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't either until I had to use it for something earlier, they added it in the upgrades note in December 2015 I believe.